# RASA Dynamic Form Behavior with both required_slots and extract_<slot_name> methods

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-sdk

These are my required_slots in my domain file.

```
forms:
  basic_info_form:
    required_slots:
      - options
      - language
      - phone
      - phone_type
      - contact_prefer
      - confirm_phone
      - other_phone
      - street_address
      - city
      - zipcode
      - confirm_address
      - full_address
      - home_members
      - race
      - hispanic
      - gender
```

I want the form to ask for the required slot in given sequence, but I have some conditions -

1. If the value of contact_prefer is 'phone_call' or 'text', the form
   should ask for the confirm_phone slot, else skip it and go direct to
   street_address.
2. If the value of confirm_phone is 'other', then it should ask for
   other_phone slot, and then continue to street_address.
3. If the value of confirm_address is 'no', then the form should ask
   for full_address slot, and then continue to the home_members slot.
   Else, continue directly to home_members slot.

I tried doing it using dynamic form behavior, but I am not able to make it work.

This is my actions file:

```html
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List, Union
from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
from rasa_sdk.forms import FormValidationAction
from rasa.nlu.utils import write_json_to_file
from rasa_sdk.events import SlotSet

class ActionSubmitForm(Action):
    
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_submit_form"

    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher, 
               tracker: Tracker, 
               domain: Dict[Text,Any])->List[Dict[Text,Any]]:
        
        #id= trunc(time())
        write_json_to_file('output/slots_values.json', tracker.slots)
        return []

class ValidateBasicInfoForm(FormValidationAction):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "validate_basic_info_form"

    async def required_slots(
        self,
        domain_slots: List[Text],
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text,Any],
    ) -> List[Text]:
        additional_slots = [""]
        if tracker.slots.get("contact_prefer") in ['phone_call','text(SMS)']:
            additional_slots.append("confirm_phone")
            

        return additional_slots + domain_slots
    
    async def extract_confirm_phone(
        self, 
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher, 
        tracker: Tracker, 
        domain: Dict
    ) -> Dict[Text, Any]:
        confirm_phone = tracker.latest_message.get("text")

        SlotSet("confirm_phone",confirm_phone)
```

Right now, I am only trying to do it to check the value of the confirm_prefer slot and extract the value of the confirm_phone slot. However, the form gets stuck on the contact_prefer slot and keeps asking the same question, no matter the input.

Below is my domain file. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```css
version: "3.1"

config:
  store_entities_as_slots: true
  
intents:
  - greet
  - goodbye
  - affirm
  - deny
  - mood_great
  - mood_unhappy
  - bot_challenge

slots:
  options:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: options
  language:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: language
  phone:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: phone
  phone_type:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: phone_type
  contact_prefer:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: true
    mappings:
    - type: custom
      action: validate_basic_info_form
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
  confirm_phone:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: phone_type
  other_phone:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: other_phone
  street_address:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: street_address
  city:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: city
  zipcode:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: zipcode
  confirm_address:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: phone_type
  full_address:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: full_address
  home_members:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: home_members
  race:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: race
  hispanic:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: hispanic
  gender:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: basic_info_form
        requested_slot: gender

responses:
  utter_greet:
  - text: "Hello!\nI'm Lucky. Do you need any help?"
  
  utter_ask_options:
  - text: "What do you need help with?\n1) Financial Advice\n2) Housing Questions"
  
  utter_ask_language:
  - text: "All right, I hope to help you with that.\nFirst, let's get to know each other. My primary language is English, but I am learning how to speak more languages. \nWhat is you primary language?\n -English\n -Spanish\n -Other"

  utter_ask_phone:
  - text: "That's awesome! My phone number is 214-739-6151. What yours?"

  utter_ask_phone_type:
  - text: "Please tell me which type of phone is this? \n Cell Phone \n Home Phone"
  
  utter_ask_contact_prefer:
  - text: "Wow so many ways to talk to you. How do you prefer I get in touch with you in the future? \n Email \n Phone Call \n Text(SMS)"
  
  utter_ask_confirm_phone:
  - text: "Which number should I use to reach out to you later? \n{phone} \nOther"
          
  utter_ask_other_phone:
  - text: "What is the new number you want me to reach you through?"
  
  utter_ask_street_address:
  - text: "Great! Did you know my home address is this website. What's your address?"
  
  utter_ask_city:
  - text: "What city do you live in?"
  
  utter_ask_zipcode:
  - text: "Oh nice! What is your Zip code?"
  
  utter_ask_confirm_address:
  - text: "Perfect. Can you verify that this is your full address?\n {street_address},{city} - {zipcode} \n- Yes\n- No"
  
  utter_ask_full_address:
  - text: "Oh no! Please help me correct it."
  
  utter_ask_home_members:
  - text: "I'm the only chatbot that lives on this webpage. How many people live at your household including you?"
  
  utter_fascinated:
  - text: "Oooh ok. You know, I have always been fascinated by humans. There is so much diversity in mankind.\nI am interested to know what type of human you are but please feel free to choose \"prefer not to say\" if you do not want to answer my next few questions."
  
  utter_ask_race:
  - text: "What ethnicity/race are you? \n-Black / African American\n-Native Hawaiian or other Pacific Islander\n-White\n-American Indian or Alaskan Native\n-Asian\n-More than one race / Other\n-Prefer Not To Say"
  
  utter_ask_hispanic:
  - text: "Are you Hispanic/Latino?\n-Yes\n-No\n-Prefer Not To Say"
  
  utter_ask_gender:
  - text: "Fun fact: I have no gender. What gender are you?\n-Female\n-Male\n-Gender Non-Conforming\n-Prefer Not To Say"

  utter_goodbye:
  - text: "Bye"
  
  utter_thank_you:
  - text: "Thank you for bearing with me! I learned a lot about you which will help me help you. \nI just have a few more questions to ask you..."
  
  utter_iamabot:
  - text: "I am Lucky, your online assitant."

actions:
  - action_submit_form
  - validate_basic_info_form

forms:
  basic_info_form:
    required_slots:
      - options
      - language
      - phone
      - phone_type
      - contact_prefer
      - confirm_phone
      - other_phone
      - street_address
      - city  
      - zipcode
      - confirm_address
      - full_address
      - home_members
      - race
      - hispanic
      - gender
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one issue with your form and it's having all slots already under the `required_slots`. You need to dynamically and based on the value of your slots which determine the `required_slots`, try to add them to the form.

Also, one suggestion is to break down your large form into multiple forms.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestion about my actions.py file? Are these the correct methods to extract slots defined using dynamic form behavior?

Comment: About listing all slots, both custom and predefined, under the required_slots in the domain.yml, I read in the RASA documentation to do that. 

Here is what it says - "In your domain file, for your form's required_slots, list all required slots, with both predefined and custom mappings." 

That is why I listed all my slots under the required_slots. Please let me know if this is not how it works.

Comment: The logic in your validator action is correct, but as I said you are adding the new `additioanl_slots` to the `domain_slots` which already has the slots under `requested_slots`. You need to dynamically add them. So you need to remove those ones that will be added dynamically from your form in the domain file.